# Kaldi toolkit Installation Error on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-16.04, kaldi

Hi I am trying to install Kaldi toolkit for speech recognition on Ubuntu 16.04. I have followed instructions in INSTALL file.

> (1) go to tools/  and follow INSTALL instructions there.

Followed procedure in INSTALL file in tools and got following output,

> $ extras/check_dependencies.sh

`../tools/extras/check_dependencies.sh: all OK.`

and executed `make` without any errors. Here are last few lines in case if you want to take a look

> $ make

```
rm -f openfst
ln -s openfst-1.6.1 openfst

Warning: IRSTLM is not installed by default anymore. If you need IRSTLM
Warning: use the script extras/install_irstlm.sh
All done OK.
```

Now I moved on to next step

> (2) go to src/ and follow INSTALL instructions there.

in src folder, executed `configure` with following output

> $ ./configure

`Configuring ...
Backing up kaldi.mk to kaldi.mk.bak ...
Checking compiler g++-4.9 ...
Checking OpenFst library in /home/xxx/Downloads/kaldi/tools/openfst ...
Doing OS specific configurations ...
On Linux: Checking for linear algebra header files ...
Using ATLAS as the linear algebra library.
Successfully configured for Debian/Ubuntu Linux [dynamic libraries] with ATLASLIBS =/usr/lib/libatlas.so.3  /usr/lib/libf77blas.so.3 /usr/lib/libcblas.so.3  /usr/lib/liblapack_atlas.so.3
CUDA will not be used! If you have already installed cuda drivers 
and cuda toolkit, try using --cudatk-dir=... option.  Note: this is
only relevant for neural net experiments
Info: configuring Kaldi not to link with Speex (don't worry, it's only needed if you
intend to use 'compress-uncompress-speex', which is very unlikely)
SUCCESS
To compile: make clean -j; make depend -j; make -j
 ... or e.g. -j 10, instead of -j, to use a specified number of CPUs
debug mode enabled...
+ exit 0`

`$ make depend` also executed without any errors. But when I execute make, I get following error (I'm not copying everything because it is very long, if anyone wants I can post full output)

> $ make

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/srinivas/Downloads/kaldi/src/online2'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/srinivas/Downloads/kaldi/src/online2'
make -C bin
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/srinivas/Downloads/kaldi/src/bin'
g++-4.9  -Wl,-rpath=/home/srinivas/Downloads/kaldi/tools/openfst/lib -rdynamic  align-equal.o ../decoder/kaldi-decoder.a ../lat/kaldi-lat.a ../lm/kaldi-lm.a ../fstext/kaldi-fstext.a ../hmm/kaldi-hmm.a ../transform/kaldi-transform.a ../gmm/kaldi-gmm.a ../tree/kaldi-tree.a ../util/kaldi-util.a ../thread/kaldi-thread.a ../matrix/kaldi-matrix.a ../base/kaldi-base.a   /home/srinivas/Downloads/kaldi/tools/openfst/lib/libfst.so /usr/lib/libatlas.so.3 /usr/lib/libf77blas.so.3 /usr/lib/libcblas.so.3 /usr/lib/liblapack_atlas.so.3 -lm -lpthread -ldl -o align-equal
align-equal.o: In function `fst::internal::FstImpl<fst::ArcTpl<fst::TropicalWeightTpl<float> > >::WriteFstHeader(fst::Fst<fst::ArcTpl<fst::TropicalWeightTpl<float> > > const&, std::ostream&, fst::FstWriteOptions const&, int, std::string const&, unsigned long, fst::FstHeader*)':
/home/srinivas/Downloads/kaldi/tools/openfst/include/fst/fst.h:745: undefined reference to `fst::FstHeader::Write(std::ostream&, std::string const&) const'
../decoder/kaldi-decoder.a(training-graph-compiler.o): In function `fst::internal::FstImpl<fst::ReverseArc<fst::ArcTpl<fst::TropicalWeightTpl<float> > > >::WriteFstHeader(fst::Fst<fst::ReverseArc<fst::ArcTpl<fst::TropicalWeightTpl<float> > > > const&, std::ostream&, fst::FstWriteOptions const&, int, std::string const&, unsigned long, fst::FstHeader*)':
/home/srinivas/Downloads/kaldi/tools/openfst/include/fst/fst.h:745: undefined reference to `fst::FstHeader::Write(std::ostream&, std::string const&) const'
../decoder/kaldi-decoder.a(training-graph-compiler.o): In function `fst::internal::FstImpl<fst::ArcTpl<fst::LogWeightTpl<float> > >::WriteFstHeader(fst::Fst<fst::ArcTpl<fst::LogWeightTpl<float> > > const&, std::ostream&, fst::FstWriteOptions const&, int, std::string const&, unsigned long, fst::FstHeader*)':
/home/srinivas/Downloads/kaldi/tools/openfst/include/fst/fst.h:745: undefined reference to `fst::FstHeader::Write(std::ostream&, std::string const&) const'
../fstext/kaldi-fstext.a(kaldi-fst-io.o): In function `fst::ReadFstKaldi(std::string)':
/home/srinivas/Downloads/kaldi/src/fstext/kaldi-fst-io.cc:34: undefined reference to `fst::FstHeader::Read(std::istream&, std::string const&, bool)'
/home/srinivas/Downloads/kaldi/src/fstext/kaldi-fst-io.cc:37: undefined reference to `fst::FstReadOptions::FstReadOptions(std::string const&, fst::FstHeader const*, fst::SymbolTable const*, fst::SymbolTable const*)'
../fstext/kaldi-fstext.a(kaldi-fst-io.o): In function `fst::internal::FstImpl<fst::ArcTpl<fst::TropicalWeightTpl<float> > >::ReadHeader(std::istream&, fst::FstReadOptions const&, int, fst::FstHeader*)':
/home/srinivas/Downloads/kaldi/tools/openfst/include/fst/fst.h:796: undefined reference to `fst::FstHeader::Read(std::istream&, std::string const&, bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'align-equal' failed
make[2]: *** [align-equal] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/srinivas/Downloads/kaldi/src/bin'
Makefile:142: recipe for target 'bin' failed
make[1]: *** [bin] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/srinivas/Downloads/kaldi/src'
Makefile:35: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've even manually searched for libraries and they are present in the location ../tools/openfst. I even tried system wide installation of openfst, but nothing worked. Any help would be appriciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using g++-5. Ubuntu 16.04 by default uses g++-5 for pre-installed packages and when I try to compile Kaldi with g++-4.9 and link with Ubuntu packages that used g++-5, linker caused undefined references. I was facing similar issue with other libraries as well

Answer (score 0):

Srinivas

I am also using ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I would suggest you to take a look into this website and follow step by step procedure. I think it will solve your problem.

http://jrmeyer.github.io/kaldi/2016/01/26/Installing-Kaldi.html

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial link but that's not the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

To solve any such errors, I've always followed these steps:

- use ***g++-4.8*** to compile kaldi source.
- add shared flag to your configure command ***e.g. CXX=g++-4.8 ./configure --shared***
- before making in src directory also make the dependencies as well ***e.g. sudo make depend CXX=g++-4.8***
- use root privileges while making and also add ***g++-4.8*** directive to your command as well e.g. ***sudo make CXX=g++-4.8***
- after that compile the online extensions using ***sudo make ext CXX=g++-4.8***

hopefully this will solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use g++-5 to compile kaldi. It will not support cuda then, as ubuntu 16.04 ships with cuda 7.5 which is incomptatible with gcc 5.

To build with support of CUDA from ubuntu 16.04 :

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-toolkit libcupti-dev g++-4.8
cd tools; make CXX=g++-4.8
cd src; CXX=g++-4.8  ./configure --shared && make-j8
```